# Plotly.relayout() giving error

Tags: javascript, jquery, plotly

[SOLVED]

I am using plotly for plotting my graphs . I am using the below code for resizing my plotly graph , when I resize my browser window.

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
     var divheight = $("#section").height();
     var divwidth = $("#section").width();

     var update = {
              width:divwidth,  // or any new width
              height:divheight // " "
            };

    Plotly.relayout('section', update);

        }).resize();
```

However I am getting the following error in the console when I try to run the code .

> plotly-basic.js:17 Uncaught bad container

PS: I am using flask for backend and Javascript , HTML for displaying the plotly plots

Can someone please help me out :(

Answer (score 1):

[SOLVED]

Well I I was trying to use "Plotly.relayout()" before the graph was created itself :)  Rectified it and errors disappeared :)